# Why does not Pandas interpolate method works when having the consecutive nan values?

Tags: python, pandas

Lets say I have following pandas Series:

`s = pd.Series([np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 0, 1, 2, 3])`

and I want to use the pandas nearest interpolate method on this data.

When I run the code

`s.interpolate(method='nearest')` - it does not do the interpolation.

When I modify the series lets say `s = pd.Series([np.nan, 1, np.nan, 0, 1, 2, 3])` then the same method works.

Do you know how to do the interpolation in the first case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two surrounding values to be able to [**inter**polate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation), else this would be [extrapolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extrapolation).

As you can see with:

```
s = pd.Series([np.nan, 1, np.nan, 0, 1, 2, 3])
s.interpolate(method='nearest')
```

only the intermediate NaNs are interpolated:

```
0    NaN  # cannot interpolate
1    1.0
2    1.0  # interpolated
3    0.0
4    1.0
5    2.0
6    3.0
dtype: float64
```

As you want the **nearest** value, a workaround could be to [`bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.bfill.html) (or `ffill`):

```
s.interpolate(method='nearest').bfill()
```

output:

```
0    1.0
1    1.0
2    1.0
3    0.0
4    1.0
5    2.0
6    3.0
dtype: float64
```

##### follow-up

> The only problem occurred when 1.  `s = pd.Series([np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan])` and 2.  `s = pd.Series([np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan])` . In the first case,
> I want to have 0 everywhere. In the second case, I want to leave it as
> it is

```
try:
    s2 = s.interpolate(method='nearest').bfill().ffill()
except ValueError:
    s2 = s.bfill().ffill()
```